# Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 78 bytes) in

Tags: memory, fatal-error, phpbb

I am using PHPbb , everything works fine,

But i am getting the following error in a single page inside admin.

```
 Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 78 bytes) in home/mytestsite/public_html/includes/template.php on line 458
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

As you can imagine, this error message occurs when PHP tries to use more memory than is avialable. I'm assuming that changing code is not an option but you CAN increase the amount of memory available to PHP.

To change the memory limit for one specific script, include a line such as this at the top of the script:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","20M");
```

The 12M (for example) sets the limit to 20 Megs. If this does not work, keep increasing the memory limit until your script fits or your server squeals for mercy.

You can also make this a permanent change for all PHP scripts running on the server by adding a line such as this to the server’s php.ini file:

```
memory_limit = 20M
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have give maximum limit ini_set("memory_limit","-1"); but still getting the same error.